# Number of replications needed for coverage probability study

Tags: confidence-interval, coverage-probability

I am constructing confidence interval based on Wald, likelihood ratio and jackknife for the parameters of a model via simulation. To evaluate which methods is preferable for the parameters, I did a coverage probability study for moderate and large samples. My issue is, I could not find the rule of thumb that how many replications is required. Anyone could help me on this?

Comment: What you are asking is very broad and without context - could you say rather more about your situation and what you are attempting to achieve? (You should generally be wary of claims that one particular sample size is appropriate as a minimum number of replications for some procedure or another...)

Comment: Hi @Silverfish, thanks for your comment. I have changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

Estimating a coverage probability is no different from estimating a proportion. In the worst case scenario, the standard error of your estimate based on $n$ replications will be $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}}$$. You can therefore choose $n$ to make this as small as desired.